# "Экскурсия в Москву". Здесь "в Москву" — обстоятельство или дополнение?

Tags: дополнение, обстоятельство

**Экскурсия в Москву запомнилась надолго.**

Здесь "в Москву" — дополнение или обстоятельство?

Comment: Я исправил пунктуацию. Если уж подписываетесь Учитель, то, пожалуйста, старайтесь соблюдать правила пунктуации. – М_Г 39 минут назад

Answer (score 3):

*Экскурсия* [какая? куда?] ***в Москву*** запомнилась надолго.

Здесь ***в Москву*** — *обстоятельственное **определение*** (атрибутивное значение осложнено обстоятельственным).

Так характеризует подобные члены предложения автор ряда школьных учебников Вера Васильевна Бабайцева.

Вот что она пишет в книге *"Анализ слова и предложения"* (М., 2014):

> Трудно "втиснуть" в прокрустово ложе традиционной классификации
>   синкретичные члены предложения, не допускающие однозначной
>   квалификации.
>
> Бесплодные многолетние дискуссии утратили остроту в связи с признанием
>   переходных синкретичных членов предложения, совмещающих значения
>   разных членов предложения.
>
> Я ввела не только в вузовские, но и в школьные учебники синкретичные
>   образования с названием *многозначные члены предложения*.

И далее:

> Вопрос — а как правильно? — в настоящее время не является актуальным,
>   хотя **в некоторых публикациях принимается лишь один компонент
>   семантики — атрибутивный**.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ,! Это из школьной тетради. То есть, можно сказать, что это определение?

Comment: Да, определение (со значением обстоятельства), т.е. подчёркивается и как определение, и как обстоятельство. Но главное значение - определение, потому что относится к существительному-подлежащему(экскурсия какая?), а обстоятельство обычно  относится к сказуемому-глаголу.